# Amazon Connect many tables to one API with Amplify AWS IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am new to amazon services AWS, and I am trying to create a database for my project (DynamoDB). I have followed the tutorial and have all installed (CLI, Amplify, etc). But when I add a new API it creates only one table and scheme. So my question is, how I can have multiple tables (User, Notifications, Promos, etc) using the same API? Or how I can go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure if you have multiple `@model` annotation in your `schema.graphql` you will have multiple tables. For example,

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Notification @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}

type Promo @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

It will create at least 3 tables, one for each. Why? Because `@model`. Read https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#usage